# Synchronous Window.show()

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

In my project I use custom component derived from `Window` to show messages. Currently I use this code:

```js
function showMessage(title, text) {
    var component = Qt.createComponent("MessageBox.qml");
    if (component.status === Component.Ready) {
        var dialog = component.createObject(parent);
        dialog.caption = title;
        dialog.message = text;
        dialog.show();
        return dialog;
    }
}
```

But now I want to use it as kind of `confirm()` in JS i.e. now it should wait till user will click appropriate button in the dialog and so returns value (true/false) after that.

One of desired usage is to validate a user form, for example:

```js
function checkAForm() {
    if(!showMessage("Warning","The field f1 is empty. Do you want to continue?"))
        return false;
    if(!showMessage("Warning","Some warning"))
        return false;
    if(!showMessage("Warning","Some another warning"))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Now this function always brings up 3 windows at the same time and returns `false`.

The first idea was to implement that with signal connect:

```js
function checkAForm() {
    var dialog1 = showMessage("...","...");
    dialog1.accepted.connect(function(){
        var dialog2 = showMessage("...","...");
        dialog2.accepted.connect(function(){
            var dialog3 = showMessage("...","...");
            dialog3.accepted.connect(function(){
                return true;
            });
        });
    });
}
```

where `accepted` is a signal of `MessageBox.qml` emitted when user clicks `Ok` button.

But this construction is too complicated and not so clear. Also I don't know what to do if use clicks `Cancel`.

So now I am looking for good idea how to implement synchronous call of Window.show() or, may be some other ideas, maybe some semaphore or something like that.

Comment: Do you mean that the modality of the dialog does not cover the time spent in the closing signal? That is, if your handler is time consuming, nothing prevents the user from doing whatever he wants, is it?

Comment: Yes, although the dialog will be modal it return from the function after show() call. It fails if I want to call several `showMessage` sequentially

Comment: QML is a declarative language so blocking or pause the code flow is not possible. If your `Window` has the flag `Qt.Dialog` and its modality is set to `Qt.WindowModal` the user should close the window clicking the right button in order to continue working with the application.

Comment: ^ The idea would be to emit a signal when that button is clicked and work with that signal.

Comment: Yes @Tarod, you are right a `Window` with `Qt.WindowModal` will block an user till the window be closed. But anyway execution continues after calling to `show()`. My target is to call several `showMessage()` sequentially, one after another. Now it will just bring up several windows at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I have understood from the comments so far, it seems that synchronicity/asynchronicity (blocking or not of the GUI thread) is perhaps not the issue here, but you want to have multiple dialog windows in a sequence, which seems to me a little like a wizard.

For that purpose, with your current approach, why not do something like this:

First you would have your custom MessageBox.qml set up like this:

```
Item {
...
    property var acceptedFunction
    property var canceledFunction
...
    Button {
        id: acceptedButton
        onClicked: { acceptedFunction() }
    }
    Button {
        id: canceledButton
        onClicked: { canceledFunction() }
    }
...
}
```

Then, in the utilizing qml:

```
    function startTheShow() {
        showFirstWindow()
    }

    function showFirstWindow() {
        var title = "First Window's Title"
        var text = "First Window's Text"
        var component = Qt.createComponent("MessageBox.qml");
        if (component.status === Component.Ready) {
            var dialog = component.createObject(parent);
            dialog.caption = title;
            dialog.message = text;
            dialog.acceptedFunction = showSecondWindow
            dialog.canceledFunction = function() { ...do something here... } //This is just for an example how you can have it also -- as an anonymous function.
            dialog.show();
        }
    }

    function showSecondWindow() {
        var title = "Second Window's Title"
        var text = "Second Window's Text"
        var component = Qt.createComponent("MessageBox.qml");
        if (component.status === Component.Ready) {
            var dialog = component.createObject(parent);
            dialog.caption = title;
            dialog.message = text;
            dialog.acceptedFunction = showThirdWindow
            dialog.canceledFunction = function() { ...do something here... } //This is just for an example how you can have it also -- as an anonymous function.
            dialog.show();
        }

    function showThirdWindow() ...and so on
```

If you fiddle with something above, you could also probably be able to do it with one general function, and an array of objects as a configuration for the window flow. Perhaps something like:

MessageBox.qml:

```
Item {
...
    property int myIndex
    property var showNextWindowFunc
    Button {
        id: acceptedButton
        onClicked: { showNextWindowFunc(myIndex+1) }
    }
    Button {
        id: canceledButton
        onClicked: { ...do some standard thing perhaps?... }
    }
...
}
```

utilizingQml.qml:

```
property var myWindowSequenceConfiguration: [
    { "title" : "Title 1", "text" : "Text 1" },
    { "title" : "Title 2", "text" : "Text 2" },
    ...
]

function showWindow(index) {
    var component = Qt.createComponent("MessageBox.qml");
    if (component.status === Component.Ready) {
        var dialog = component.createObject(parent);
        dialog.myIndex = index
        dialog.caption = myWindowSequenceConfiguration[index]["title"];
        dialog.message = myWindowSequenceConfiguration[index]["text"];
        dialog.showNextWindowFunc = showWindow
        dialog.show();
    }
}

function startTheShow() {
    showWindow(0)
}
```

---

Ok, I came up with yet another variation in the theme:

MessageBox.qml:

```
Item {
...
    property var acceptedFuncParams
    property var canceledFuncParams
    property var acceptedFunc
    property var canceledFunc
    Button {
        id: acceptedButton
        onClicked: { acceptedFunc(acceptedFuncParams) }
    }
    Button {
        id: canceledButton
        onClicked: { canceledFunc(canceledFuncParams) }
    }
...
}
```

utilizingQml.qml:

```
property var myWindowSequenceConfiguration: [
    { "title" : "Title 1", "text" : "Text 1" },
    { "title" : "Title 2", "text" : "Text 2" },
    ...
]

function showWindow(index) {
    var component = Qt.createComponent("MessageBox.qml");
    if (component.status === Component.Ready) {
        var dialog = component.createObject(parent);
        dialog.caption = myWindowSequenceConfiguration[index]["title"];
        dialog.message = myWindowSequenceConfiguration[index]["text"];
        dialog.acceptedFuncParams = index+1
        dialog.acceptedFunc = showWindow
        dialog.canceledFunc = function() { ...do something here... }
        dialog.show();
    }
}

function startTheShow() {
    showWindow(0)
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Miika Pirttilä for your detailed answer but I'm afraid that isn't what I'm looking for. That's my mistake, it was not clear enough. I've updated the answer, hope that now it became more clear.

Comment: Ah, wait ... just now I've get your idea. In general, you suggest to separate my `checkAForm()` into 6 functions. I mean 3 dialogs - 6 functions. for each dialog - one for `accepted` action and one for `canceled`? I'm going to try it now.

Comment: My first suggestion might be the clearest and easiest to implement. It's drawback is that a lot of similar boilerplate code is created, which I don't like, but it's not a big issue. I edited it a little, it had a copy/paste error. Added the third function.

Comment: Also, you need to call dialog.destroy() at some point for such dynamically created dialogs in order to delete the objects.